# Send a X509 Certificate in Https Request header using rest template

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate

Hi I am working on a task which requires me to make an HTTPS call to a server.
This server requires our certificate in the request Header to be added separately with header parameters as "clientCert".
I have gone through a lot of links on how it can be done but I could not make it possible.
And might be possible that did not understand anything out of the given solution.

I want to send a certificate in the request header with the header parameter "clientCert".
Can someone please help me on acheiving this. Please do not consider it as duplicate of any other SO link as they did not work for me. I am using Spring Boot please find my code below.

```
@Configuration
public class SSLConfig{
 private static final String KEY_PASS="password"

static{

System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", SSLConfig.class.getClassLoader().getResource("client.jks").getFile())
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", KEY_PASS)

System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", SSLConfig.class.getClassLoader().getResource("client.jks").getFile())
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", KEY_PASS)

javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostNameVerifier(){

       public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession sslSession){
           return "serverhostname".equals(hostname);
        }
  });
}


   @Bean
   public RestTemplate restTemplate(){
    return new RestTemplate()
   }
}
```

And then in my service

```
@Service
public class ConnectorService{
 
@Autowired
RestTemplate restTemplate;

  public void getData(){
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
  
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.set("clientCert", <Here I need put my X509 certificate>);
    HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
    ResponseEntity<String> response  = 
    restTemplate.exchange("https://www.test.com/getData",HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);

    System.out.println(response.getBody());

  }

}
```

Comment: If you know where your certificate file resists, can't you just read it as a byte array, encode it somehow (base64) and simply put it as a string? However, putting a ssl certificate inside a http request is not a way to perform a https call.

Comment: I dont know why the API requires it. But they need it in the request header. Is there any better way  for doing this.

Comment: I think there mustn't be any difference between this file and any other file you can send this way. Have you tried simply reading the file and putting it as a string in the header?

Comment: trying it now. I was not sure whether we can do it like this.As the certificate required in the header is the one which we will be creating by ourself

Comment: This header has nothing to do with the way the secure connection is created. If the server trusts your certificate in SSL handshakes, you can send anything through the connection.